# What is the cheapest Bitcoin -> prepaid VISA/Mastercard service?

Tags: visa, sell-bitcoins

I am looking for the cheapest Bitcoin to prepaid VISA/Mastercard service for the amount of $5000. I have noticed some with a maximum of $100, and inquired whether it would be possible to increase this cap. It is really not interesting to have to buy 50 cards, and ensure that one empties each of them. $1000 on each card is acceptable though.

The card needs to work for purchases in any country.

Answer (score 10):

That's quite a lot of money to try to load onto a prepaid card and likely not something you'll find easily done.

Some options are:

- http://www.okpay.com/en/services/debit-card/index.html
- https://www.aurumxchange.com/cards Expect to get their cards program [back soon](https://www.aurumxchange.com/cards).

With OKPay, you can reload using bitcoins, which OKPay will exchange into USDs for you ([the cost of this was just reduced from 5% to 2.5% of transfered amount](http://okpay.com/ms/services/fees-e-currency.html)). 
With AurumXChange, you can reload using USDs from Mt. Gox codes.

For that amount though you'll probably be best arranging trades with some buyers willing to exchange Moneypak to you.  For instance, on the #bitcoin-otc there often times are traders looking for BTC and for larger amounts will go out and buy a MoneyPak to do the trade.

You can load a number of different prepaid cards with MoneyPak, up to $1,000 each.  See the Prepaid Cards section for the list: https://www.moneypak.com/WhoAccepts.aspx

Along the same lines, you might find a trader that would deposit cash at Western Union to reload a Western Union prepaid card.

Comment: Aurum Exchange has a different domain ("exchange", vs. "xchange") and doesn't seem to handle Bitcoin.

Comment: Since May 2013, [OKPay no longer accepts Bitcoin](https://www.okpay.com/en/company/news/bitcoin-okpay-terms-of-use.html)

Comment: [Paxum doesn't seem to accept Bitcoin either](https://www.paxum.com/payment/fees.php?view=views/fees.xsl). This answer needs a big update.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend http://www.xmlgold.net. They offer a pretty good system which allows you to buy a [prepaid mastercard](http://www.xmlgold.eu) with bitcoins and load the card with bitcoins. They have low fees.

Comment: The Mastercard itself is expensive to use, and they do not make it easy to see how much they take for converting from Bitcoins to Eur.

Comment: xmlgold.net is dead, and the .eu site refuses connections from the US.

Answer (score 4):

http://bitcashretail.com/ (service is now dead)

Quote from site:

> We will provovide you a digital Visa card for the spot price of Mtgox for a Bitcoin equivalent of a $7usd service charge. Available to registed users only!

Comment: Welcome to the site. One upvote to get you started. I could only see that they have visa cards for 25$, which is too low.

Comment: Are there any people describing their experience with this service (BitCashLotto.com , IIUC)?

Comment: [BitcashRetail is dead](http://isup.me/http://bitcashretail.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Visit en.bitcointalk.org - Their you will find awesome services!

Comment: Seems like the price is 27€ for a 25€ virtual card when I also count in the poor exchange rate they offer. This is the cheapest I have seen so far.

Comment: I have tested this now, and it works perfectly!

Comment: @David: what service have you tested that you have found on the Bitcoin forums? This answer would be more useful if it mentioned some services.

Comment: @cryptal The original answer mentioned CryptCard.org, but that service has been closed down.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try CentreGold for this service but you will have to transfer them Liberty Reserve (USD) from your Gox account.

https://centregold.com/public/debitcard.php

Answer (score 3):

I have got an XMLGold Prepaid MasterCard from PFS and it can be loaded instantly with bitcoins during a daytime, the card cost just 2 Bitcoins and delivery was included. You can get the card here: [instant bitcoin mastercard](https://www.xmlgold.eu/en/site/cardInfo.html)

Answer (score 3):

Why not using Bitcurex card?
It's the cheapest and most anonymous way. For 5000 USD you would need 2 cards only, and you don't have to sign for the shipping for two cards.
With a bit of searching you can even load it through an [IBAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) account from different exchanges, not just Bitcurex. (a bit of searching required)
I'm using them all the time and I'm very happy with them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Ecardone.com](http://ecardone.com) 
more info [here](http://ecardone.com/prepaid-card/). They offer a prepaid MasterCard debit card that can be loaded with Bitcoin for $3 plus 2%. You also need to buy Bitcoins through their exchange, which costs you an additional 3% or so.

Comment: Right now they have a fee of 3% for depositing BTC because of them offering lower exchange rates. This is so sneaky that I will be reluctant to use them as I will always have to do the manual work of comparing their exchange rates to those on MtGox.com