# Bitcoin -> prepaid VISA/Mastercard service (2014 edition)?

Tags: bitcoin-credit-card

I have read the answers in [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/what-is-the-cheapest-bitcoin-prepaid-visa-mastercard-service) question here... But it is incredibly outdated. OKPay no longer accepts Bitcoin to creditcard. bitcashretail.com is down. xmlgold.eu results into an error. Centregold results into a page not found. ecardone.com is seized by the "Global Illicit Financial Team"
Etc, etc, etc...

So I think it is time for a new edition of the bitcoin to virtual creditcard question.

Comment: I think the current tone of the discussion is "MasterCard tries to destroy bitcoin" so there is little hope to get such thing: http://www.teribuhl.com/2013/10/22/mastercard-hates-bitcoins/

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa How about Visa?

Comment: Any a clue whether instantlybank.com is trustworthy or not?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a single available solution to go to a general VISA/MC/AMEX card in the US today. Money Transmitter laws (and a host of other regulations) make this a very difficult proposition at the moment.

Some other countries don't have the same issues today, like Canada http://paymentweek.com/2013-11-4-canada-introduces-bitcoin-debit-card-services-238461/ but these solutions are also still in development.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm looking at this combinations :

btc-e -> egopay.com -> payeer.com -> direct card deposit (visa OR mastercard international)

okpay does not let you deal with money from crypto coins exchanges but you can still cashout money from egopay / payeer / etc.

So another option is :

btc-e -> egopay.com -> okpay -> okpay card

the transfers will cost a lot of money ... I'm still looking for a better option ..

Comment: I think you are trying to describe an answer, however it is hard to follow what you are suggesting. Perhaps you could fill it in with a bit more text?

Answer (score 0):

XML gold offer this service:

https://www.xmlgold.eu/

And so long as you are not a US citizen so do OKPay again.

https://www.okpay.com/en/index.html

Answer (score -2):

You may want to try https://www.BuyBitcoins.com

They are a little more expensive than other bitcoin exchanges, but allow you buy bitcoins with prepaid credit cards. (Visa only)

Comment: Read the question before posting an answer.  He is looking to load a prepaid card with bitcoins. not the reverse.